# Questions with proprietary or confidential information

Tags: discussion, intellectual-property

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

Every once in a while, when I am posting code to either ask or answer a question, I find myself cleaning out all the references to the company I'm working for and scanning for any other proprietary or confidential info. I figure that if I'm doing it others are doing it, and that means that occasionally, there are going to be pieces of code that we miss:

```
using System;

namespace HotOrNotDotCom
{
    public class Login
    {
        int timesBeforeLockout = 4;
        public Login(string username, string password)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What's the right thing to do in this circumstance? If we come across something like this, should we edit the info out? Has SO ever gotten a takedown request? Has a user ever suffered as a result of posting code he or she has written as part of their work?

Comment: @casperOne Isn't the other question a duplicate of this one instead of this question being a duplicate of that one? Because this is older?

Comment: @AnishGupta Age doesn't always indicate priority when closing duplicates.  That question is the better question, and the accepted answer better represents current thinking and guidance for this subject matter.

Answer (score 27):

Even if you do edit it out, it will still be in the revision history, so it is not advisable.

Flag the post for moderator attention and recommend they delete the revision entirely.

Comment: True. See also [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)

Comment: Note that given the recent update to [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86202/138432) it looks like this advice is now out of date. See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43820/138432) here or either [Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/138432)'s answer or [Yannis Rizos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132118/138432)'s answer to the [other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like a combination of these would be best.

What I would suggest is:

- If you can, **edit the code** to remove the offending information.

  - This won't remove it from the revision history, but will *hide* the information *in* the revision history, minimising exposure to the problem.
- If you don't have edit privileges, **flag the post for moderator attention**.

  - A moderator will then know to edit out the offending information for you.
- Even if you *can* edit the question/answer, flag it for moderator attention.

  - Site moderators can delete the post and get in touch with someone on the team who can [remove the revision from the history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86202/138432).

Note, even if you don't have edit privileges, you *could* submit the change to the peer review queue. Unfortunately this does draw attention to the problem in a rather more public way (i.e. everyone with [edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/138432)), so it might be better to just *flag for the moderators attention*.

Comment: For something like this, I don't think you *could* be overly loud. If there is information in the revision history that, from a legal standpoint, shouldn't be there, be as noise as you can (short of calling someone on their home phone at 4AM or,  depending on what hours they keep, 10AM).

Comment: @BCS - The trick is being loud to people who can do something about it (stack exchange developers and community managers can delete revisions) while being quiet with **everyone else**.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is rarely done, and nearly always done as a *courtesy* to folks who've posted something they regret (or *should* regret). I've routinely refused requests that smell like attempts to censor information *someone else* finds... Inconvenient.