# Passwords in Questions

Tags: discussion, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

I just answered a question on SO which included a complete connection string for the user's production database.  (No, I will not link to it)

What should I do about that?

Comment: Change it to hunter2

Comment: The user in question has changed his password.  However, my question still stands.  What should we do about such people in the future?

Comment: Clean it out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to flag this type of thing to the mods and send an email to team@stackoverflow.com to see if they will edit the revision where the password appears.

It probably happens fairly infrequently but I'm sure the mods and team won't mind dealing with it due to the critical nature of such a mistake.

That said, if it happens again then there's no helping some folk, like the Stack Overflow user  I watched one day posting his SQL connection string into the #stackoverflow IRC channel.

Comment: Edit, then ask for the previous revision to be removed altogether: see [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)