# Who has the privilege to delete a revision?

Tags: support, revisions-list, revision-redaction

I saw a PPT posted by Jeff that showed a revision page which had the delete revision function, like this:

[image]

But I have never seen this functionality on SO's revision pages. I guess that's because I don't have the privilege.

My questions is: Who has the privilege to delete a revision?

Answer (score 38):

We no longer hard delete revisions. Instead, we now redact them.

And currently, [moderators have that ability too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191121/208518). So instead of contacting us if you for some reason accidentally posted sensitive information, please proceed by editing your post to have said information removed and replaced with dummy text/data/code that fulfills the same purpose — [**take care not to break context of the post, especially if answers are already present**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327145/1328704) — and then flag the post for moderator attention (this is covered in [this help center page](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)). In both the flag and the edit descriptions, please try to be as descriptive as possible (p.e., mention "removed IP and e-mail addresses" or "removed e-mail address and password").

If the answers already used sensitive information before you noticed and edited it out, please do the same thing for them.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Accidentally posted my last name as part of an error in Terminal on my Mac once.

Comment: Who can see redacted revisions? Any mod?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Nope - after a redaction is complete - mods can see that a redaction happened but not what the redacted content was. I believe you have to be a CM to be able to see the actual content.

Comment: Redacted revisions aren't accessible to any non-staff member, @ShadowTheKidWizard. And it's not easy for staff members to get access to them either — the revisions are purged from the DB, so we'd only be able to access them if that revision made its way to an old back-up.

Comment: @JNat so it's hard deletion (that's exactly the definition for purged from the DB), just getting a catchy short name. :)

Comment: guess the distinction I was trying to make at the time was that the way we purge the content is different: before, _the whole revision_ would be gone, and now we redact only part of it. Feel free to edit to make it more technically correct if you will, @ShadowTheKidWizard ;)

Comment: The answer is fine. Thanks! :)