# Is it possible to delete sensitive info fully on SE, even from revision history?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

If you copy and paste some code and accidentally forget to remove sensitive info, is there a way to get rid of that information, so even the revision history doesn't contain it?

Comment: if the information is sensitive like a password or API key, you already released it into the wild. Change it now. No, not in 5 minutes: NOW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just flag for a moderator, or send an email to team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: would a moderator remove certain words? or would that be over asking him?

Comment: @Andy, if you ask it nice, I'm sure they will do.

Comment: Moderators cannot erase the history either, for what I know. But the team [can delete certain revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision).

Comment: @Arjan True, but they can get a dev to do it if you flag it

Comment: Moderators CANNOT permanently delete ANYTHING.

Comment: We can redact sensitive info so it's not part of the public revision history; mods have this ability too.

Answer (score 4):

- Firstly edit the post yourself to remove the sensitive information.
- Then custom flag your post and for for whatever previous revisions need to be redacted to be redacted.

If you don't edit the post yourself you're relying on the mod to determine what should and should not be redacted. Since you know what it is you want removed and that's something you can do yourself, you should do that. Your flag may be rejected if you don't do this if the mod cannot determine what it is that needs redacting.

If your post is a question, check that any existing answers haven't copied your sensitive information, and try if possible not to invalidate any existing answers when you edit your question.

Note that moderator redaction can take some time as it requires [two moderators to complete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision).

Even if you do all this it's possible that scrapers and archivers have already seen your post and copied it. There's nothing we can do about that I'm afraid, once the genie has escaped it's very hard to get it back in the bottle.