# Are my deleted answers visible to others?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

I have deleted my answer and after refreshing the page my answer is highlighted and shows deleted by owner.

Is the same with others who see my answer or will it not be shown?

Comment: The [FAQ] might help you here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean

Comment: In short - yes, any user with 10,000 reputation or more will see your answer if he's viewing the question page. Only moderators can see it listed in your profile though. You can't have it completely removed - see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87794/how-to-delete-questions-with-answers-and-comments) as reference.

Comment: what about answer that I gave and cannot see anymore because question was deleted, I would like to keep track of that answer  because was good exercise to me

Answer (score 34):

Only users with 10k reputation or above can see deleted answers if they are viewing the question you answered, and only mods can see them listed on your profile.

This is for a very good reason - so that if valuable content is removed, for example if a user decides to remove all their own posts in a fit of anger, we can flag to undelete it.

I wouldn't worry too much about the fact some users can see your post. All of us have a few bad answers we've removed after re-reading. Actually, removing your answer on review is a *good sign* that you're committed to giving quality answers and there's even a badge for it.

Comment: I wanna test that [/goes off in a self-induced fit of anger] ;)

Comment: Is it possible to signal to a mod that an answer was useful but erroneously deleted by the author? The second (now deleted) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024505/how-to-use-dplyr-group-by-and-get-indices-each-distinct-grouping) question is one example

Comment: *“Only users with 10k reputation”* - does that mean *even the OP* can't see answers that were given in response **to their own question**, if OP has under 10k rep? Because censorship on that level would be outrageous. The author of the question should have the most say regarding which content is “valuable”. Even if it is deemed by the mods almighty as being unsuitable for the rest of the community, an answer is still communication *intended for the OP* (at the very least). Can you please clarify whether the under 10k blackout policy includes concealment from the original poster?

Comment: @Mentalist The user who posted this is deleted and *can't* clarify, but I can clarify on their behalf: yes, if an answer is deleted, the OP of that question can no longer see it either. If the OP objects to that answer's deletion, on the basis that it helped them, they can always appeal on the per-site Meta, and either it can be undeleted, or the mods/users that deleted it can explain their reasoning (e.g. the answer may have been plagiarised, ChatGPT, or otherwise in contravention of site rules).