# How can I see other users' answers to a deleted question that I posted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

In the list of deleted questions that I posted, I can sometimes see that the question had answers. But when I click on the question, I can see both the question and the comments, but I cannot see the answers. The answers are not mine. How can I see those answers?

Examples:

- https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/is-there-any-treatment-for-a-collapsed-vein
- https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108277/how-to-obtain-a-systems-biology-of-a-cell-in-a-variable-other-than-the-chemical

Comment: I just checked, and you *can* see answers on your deleted questions. If you don't see an answer, it means the answer itself was deleted, so you need 10k rep to see it. Post a link to the question and someone might be able to verify this. (high rep user on that site or a mod.)

Comment: Another option is that you're viewing one of your deleted *answers*. In such case you'll see your answer and the question, but not any other answer.

Comment: As Shadow said, one reason you may not be able to see the answer is because it was deleted *before* the question was deleted. Since it was deleted separately, rather than along with your question, you can't see it unless you have enough reputation to access moderation tools. Please edit your post here to add a link to the question you're talking about so we can reach out to a high-reputation user on the site (if it's a different site) and confirm if that's the case.

Comment: done w the edit @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog.. Is there not any way to see the answers if they were deleted first? It might still be a useful answer..

Comment: Thanks! I've gone ahead and pinged the two sites' moderators in their respective chat rooms with a link to your question to see what happened to your questions' answers. Their chat rooms are a bit inactive, though, so it may take some time before they respond.

Comment: In addition to Sonic's attempt in chat, you can raise a custom flag on the site with your deleted question, and in the flag ask to undelete the answers. This way you won't know the reason for deletion, but it might work i.e. mods will undelete.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Pinging works without problems ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I can only answer this for the biology question: The "answer" was a spam answer which was deleted on Dec 15, 2022, the question was deleted as "RemoveAbandonedQuestions" by the system on June 3, 2023.

It makes a difference if an answer is deleted with the question (question is deleted, answer as well) or if the answer is independently deleted from the question. In the first case, users should be able to see the answers, in the second only users with at least 10k reputation. I think this [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303221/visibility-of-deleted-answers-to-deleted-questions) here on Meta explains this further.

Does this answer your question?