# How can it be that people know my email adress?

Tags: discussion, email, security, privacy

Hi,

I have a Stack Overflow account and I once asked a question about mounting sparse bundles. Now I just received an email from someone I don't know:

> Hi you,
>
> I just found your question about hiding mounted sparse bundles on stackoverlow. I just want to ask, if you got a working solution and if you could may send me the needed code. Im trying for days to get it working, but I don't find any solution… That would be really great! I also want to mount a sparse bundle without showing it in the Finder…

Problem is, I have never, ever posted my email adress on Stack Overflow, so how can this happen? This is not the first email like this I've received.

Comment: Well, you did, I found it in 10 seconds.  Fix you github link.

Comment: Something to note: even if an address is hidden on your github profile the address is still visible in commits you make.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your user profile links to your github page where you posted your email address.
I assumed something like this so I just went to your profile page and followed the links you posted there.
Apart from moderators no one can see your email address you entered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Great, thx. I think I'll add a comment to that in my biography box. Didn't know GitHub made my email adress publicly visible, oh well.

Comment: @Radek Well, they do say **Email (Publicly visible!)** on 'Public Profile' page. But you can always hide it again.

Comment: @rightfold note that the email address used on GitHub now can be kept private! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18186072/6309

Answer (score 9):

Um...

1. Open [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142019/radek-pro-grammer)
2. Follow link to http://github.com/radeks
3. See your E-Mail address

:)

Comment: Bad form putting someone else's e-mail address out in public like that.

Comment: @Al fair point, removed.

Comment: And finally we can validate if [this is true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)...

Comment: I don't know if *anybody* can delete a first revision, @Arjan.

Comment: @mmyers, I assume the following [usage scenario from Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision/86202#86202) most probably applies to first revisions: *"User posts his or her password or SSN or {sekrit thing here} in a post. Don't laugh, it has happened. Revision has to be destroyed."* So I *guess* the developers can just click that "delete" link for the original revision too. But: just guessing!

Comment: Looks like to really remove the e-mail from public view, Pekka needs to delete this whole answer.

Comment: @Cawas yeah, I will do that (unless @Arjan there is an experiment running with this? Are you waiting for mod feedback?)

Comment: Damn Pekka, why took you 59 seconds to reply? were you sleeping or something?