# Can we flag for details to be removed from a question, and its edit-history?

Tags: feature-request

Every now and then a user, typically new, will post a question that features some form of database-connection and, after the copy & paste, will forget to remove their username and password<sup>1</sup> or, in other cases, will include their (or at least *an*) email address in their question<sup>2</sup> (for the same reason, I assume).

Would it be possible to flag a question for a moderator, or perhaps developer, edit to remove such details from the edit history of a question? **Not** remove the original question (though that might be easier), but *just* those details?

---

1. Linking to the question for its comment from @alex, rather than the edits, for reference only in trying to support my request rather than giving away details: [how to check if email address exists. validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087282/how-to-check-if-email-address-exists-validation)
2. [send iframe with youtube in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339297/send-iframe-with-youtube-in-email-body)

---

**Edited**

1. to respond to @Cody Gray's comment that mods might not have the access-rights to remove details from the edit history.
2. to clarify the question title.

Comment: I think one important question is whether moderators can actually remove information from the edit history. I'm not sure. That might have to be done by one of the devs.

Comment: @Cody, that's absolutely true. I had considered that but I guess I was hoping for, uh, 'spontaneous clarification' from one of the diamond-mods, or devs. Ah, optimism... =/

Comment: Apparently developers can delete revisions, moderators cannot. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision/86202#86202

Comment: @Brian, +1 for a good find; but would the original post count as a 'revision' or is it in some way sacrosanct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIRC, some of our internal dev-only tools can be used in a way that causes edit history to be expunged (in particular, our bulk signature-removal tool, which doesn't leave revisions as we don't want to spam the front page when we remove 200 identical signature lines by a single user).

However! In many ways I'm reluctant to use it for such; that data is already public. Regardless of the duration, or the fact that it was silly to expose it - it ***has*** now been exposed. The only safe course of action is to change password, cancel the credit-card, whatever. Rewriting the edit history is a false blanket of security, and saying "yup, that's now gone" is ***entirely*** missing the point: the horse has bolted... don't bother spending time shutting the door.

Comment: Hmm. On the other hand, while it's already public it's unlikely to have been cached by Google already, certainly if it's flagged quickly enough, so it's been, potentially, reversibly-published. And the answer from @Brian Reichle's link (in comments to the question) suggests that Jeff is at least sympathetic to the proposed use-case. I make the request as a cushion against accidents, rather than stupidity-prevention/limitation.

Comment: @David I suspect you are wrong, as I've searched very specific terms on recent questions and the question itself has appeared as a Google result. This was in a matter of an hour or less, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Agreed, but let's say it's an SSN (perhaps not even their own) that may take weeks to replace.  We could mitigate the visibility within reason instead of daily worsening the problem.

Comment: @Rick yeah, that might make sense to edit out

Comment: So does that mean we should never flag such posts for cleaning at all then?  I've [found a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329114) that had a username and password in it which I've flagged and edited it out myself.  It was marked invalid (slightly annoyed by that) and the info still remains in the history.  My concerns were valid AFAIK, only it was probably something that didn't need action.  Isn't there a "valid but needs no action" response that should have been used or was this really invalid?