# Complete removal of information/edit information

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)
>   [Can we flag for details to be removed from a question, and its edit-history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/can-we-flag-for-details-to-be-removed-from-a-question-and-its-edit-history)

Is it possible to remove sensitive data from a post? For example, if someone posts their sql username and password in a question; if they remove it, it is still available if you look at the `edit` history. So is it possible to completely remove this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Edit out the information and then flag the post for moderator attention. We can't do the deletion but know some people who can (i.e. the Community Team).

Depending on the time of day/day of week the offending revision will be removed sooner or later.

Comment: ...and change the password. It's been exposed, act!

Comment: @Arjan - I'm assuming that it's not the OP's sensitive information!