# How to handle accidentally posted account credentials

Tags: discussion, moderation, declined-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

I've now twice come across a situation where a new user copy & pastes their code or server configuration file, accidentally revealing their account names and passwords/authentication secrets.  In both cases, I edited the passwords out and flagged for moderator attention (since the passwords would obviously still be in the revision history).

The [first time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8075056/201952), the account secrets were removed from the original post, so there's no public history with the poster's account information.

The [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8630883/201952), the flag was declined with a rather harsh explanation:

> declined - An important lesson will be learned. Also, only devs can delete that.

Indeed, it was reckless for the poster to just copy and paste his web.config without redacting usernames and passwords; however, do we really want to leave a publicly-accessible copy of this sensitive account information?  Even if he heeds my comment urging him to change his passwords, there's still very useful information regarding his configuration and account names, should someone try to attack his servers.

How should these kinds of situations be handled?  Do we really want to say, "too bad, better luck next time" after someone's server gets owned?

Comment: Indeed, only developers can delete it, [but they have a fancy button for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision). And I'd kind of expect moderators to pass such flags to the developers.

Comment: @Arjan: So what's the status of my flag?  Since my flagging summary says "declined", I assume the flag is closed, and won't be reviewed by a developer.

Comment: A developer probably won't be reviewing your flags anyway - it's up to the moderators to pass it on if a revision removal is found.

Comment: I guess @random answered my question then -- the entire question has been deleted.

Comment: Ah, see the most upvoted answer in the duplicate! (Anyone above 10k reputation can probably still see the deleted question, but well.)

Comment: @josh3736 That doesn't actually solve the problem with the password. 10k users will still be able to see it.

Comment: BTW: it doesn't matter what we *want* - even if you get a dev to destroy the revision, there's no telling who's already seen it, cached it, etc. In theory, it's even possible for a data-dump to have been created and distributed prior to the deletion. It's one thing to make a mistake and post the stuff, but anyone sane should *immediately* change any credentials so exposed - regardless of whether or not the revision gets wiped. FWIW: I just deleted the post. Easier than bugging devs on Christmas.

Comment: @lunboks: Worse -- with [this plugin](http://stackapps.com/questions/2505/stack-exchange-deleted-question-viewer), you just need 500 rep to see the deleted question.

Comment: @josh3736, lunboks: Just FYI: They've fixed several things since I last updated the plugin, so it probably won't work properly anymore. I haven't tested it lately. I'll test it and update the page eventually...

Comment: @lunboks, Jeremy: Worked for me.  *shrug*

Comment: @josh3736 - you have enough rep on SE to edit most things; I suspect you're able to get in because of that (i.e., the recent fixes effectively raise the bar to 2K from 500).

Comment: @NineShogsShogging: So, you want us to bug you every time someone puts their sql password into a question?  I mean, its friggen pointless.  You can't put it back in the bottle; they have to change whatever password or confidential information they exposed.  *Have to*.  Pretending that it can be undone by deletion would just give them the excuse to pretend they aren't horribly exposed.

Comment: @wont: actually, i think you should probably just delete the post in most circumstances. If it does need to live, THEN ping a dev.