# Answer history editing

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

In one of my answers I've put some information I don't want to be publicly available.

Is it possible to remove that data from the answer history?

If yes - where could I write to get such a support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag it with an appropriate message - developers (with more power than mods) can and have in the past "super deleted" revisions that need to vanish. Don't make a habit of it though!

Comment: Yeah, it is the first time for all my 2 years and 1720 answers :-)

Comment: @zerkms - I mostly just added that comment there in case someone else saw it and burned 50 flags on "super delete revision X please" - might make me rather unpopular if they used this as justification :)

Answer (score 3):

Flag it for moderator attention. When a moderator will see the flag, he will immediately delete the post (which could not be deleted by the OP, if the post is a question with up-voted answers), edit out the relevant part, and ping a Community coordinator for removing the previous revision from the history of the post.

If a developer sees the flag, the flag will be handled directly from who can remove revisions from the history of the post.

If the post is an answer, you can flag it, and then delete it. Diamond users still see the deleted posts (as 10k users do), and you will limit the visibility of that information to 1ok users, and diamond users; other users will not be able to see deleted posts.