# Deeply delete a post

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

I inadvertently placed data that is private to me in an SO question.  I thought about editing, but realize that the edit history is available to others.  I deleted the question successfully, but learned here on meta that users at a high enough reputation level can see those too.

I realize that it was my flub, but is there any step I can take to make this flub completely private?

Thanks.

Comment: Delete it, edit it, flag it. Then, change any passwords you might inadvertently revealed, since who knows who saw it in the meanwhile?

Comment: If you realize it within the first 5 minutes you can edit it out in the grace period and it won't be in the revision history.

Comment: I've destroyed the revision with your password in it, BTW. And yeah, you caught the error in time to have done what juergen suggests instead of deleting - if you stealth-edit, the original revision is gone without a trace... For future reference. Also, change your password.

Comment: Thanks @juergend.  I guess I missed the 5min window.  I think closing this was incorrect because it's not at all an exact duplicate of the ref'd question, which covers how to handle someone else's flub.  I'm left wondering what to do.  Flagging/editing seem to me to be ways of calling attention to the error.