# How to email a Stack Overflow moderator?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, moderators, contact

How can I email a Stack Overflow moderator? I have an urgent request that I want to fulfill as soon as possible.

My account has been disabled so I cannot use flagging. This account of mine got suspended again so I cannot post any question here. I have one more account that I use frequently (I needed more than one account because there is a limitation to the number of questions you can post in a day), named TechGeeky. I need to delete that account, because I used to work for one company last year and mistakenly posted some questions containing some information about that company. I got a call today regarding the same and they wanted me to delete that account of mine as soon as possible and make sure nobody can see the content of my questions.

So I started editing all the questions, but Andrew Barber suspended my account today and I cannot do anything. I was removing stuff that was resembling my company information. By mistake I have posted my company internal links and name. It's a very urgent situation for me. I am not sure what I should do. They want me to remove it as soon as possible. I need to delete those questions from my account or delete my account forever so that they don't come after me again.

Answer (score 18):

I've responded to your main account and unsuspended it. Follow the instructions I've provided there.

In the future, if you do post proprietary code and feel the need to edit it, anonymize variables, etc. without destroying the original question. Flag us when you've done so and ask for us to hard-delete the original revisions from the database. We'll pass that along to the people who can do so. Otherwise, edits like this look like someone rage quitting, and we try to stop that so that good content isn't lost from the site.

Also, please don't operate more than one account in order to exchange votes between them.

Comment: Just don't operate more than one account for any purpose whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I am working on it as soon as I am done. I will let you know. Appreciated your help again.

Comment: @Brad Larson: I have sent you an email. I am not able to edit more as it has some restriction that I can edit only 10 posts. Is it possible for you to remove those restriction.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Yes, I will make sure from now onwards. Thanks.

Comment: I have few more posts that i want to remove the edited version of the question. Where should I provide that? I haven't got a reply yet of the message I have sent so that I can reply to those message with more posts.

Comment: @Brad: I have few other post/question that I want to delete the original version of the question. So where should I send out those posts/questions? Any help will be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 7):

You can't email the moderators, but you can contact a Community Manager using https://stackoverflow.com/contact, or somebody from the [Stack Exchange Team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) (there are also Community Managers listed).

Answer (score 7):

If it is highly sensitive information, the team can remove data from the database so that it doesn't appear even in the revision history. They did this for me on dba.SE earlier this year when a user inadvertently posted private contact information into a question. Editing it out was not deemed sufficient, but I suppose it would depend on the nature of the information. If you point out the posts in question I am sure someone will help out with flags to remove the data.

More info:

[What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

Comment: But right now my account is suspended so I cannot do anything.

Comment: @FerhanJamal that's why I said, have someone else flag them. Unfortunately since you've put the information on here and subsequently had your account suspended, the price you'll have to pay is showing a few more people the sensitive information before it can get properly deleted.