# Does the flagging history summary need improvement?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, flag-history

It is not easy form me to understand the [**flagging history summary**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/220577). I think it needs  a separator (**border** or **underline**) to differentiate the total number and breakdown of that total.

> [image]

As suggested by Stijn it should be something like this

> [image]

Comment: You know that your flags are supposed to be confidential, right? *cough* :P

Comment: Well, those ones were actually just the simple off-topic questions, and they were all helpful. I think what's worse is handing out your your invalid-flag number.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or

Comment: They don't *have* to be confidential, we kust keep the, that way for you.

Comment: Yeah. But you probably want it to be confidential. That being said, yours doesn't look bad (better than mine). It's linked being naked. Yeah, there are nudists, but you probably aren't one.

Comment: I've made a quick [mockup](http://i.imgur.com/LokBmgx.png), you can add it to your post if you wish.