# Is there a way to hide edit history of question?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

If I want to edit a question, is there any way to not let anyone else see the previous version?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or

Answer (score 17):

No, the the idea of providing that edit history is to maintain *total transparency* about what is being done with a post.

There are limited cases where we may *redact* certain information that was posted inadvertently (e.g. highly-sensitive or personal information like a password), but you would need to 'flag' the post for moderator attention or use the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the site. Normally, we do not allow the hiding or removal of edit history.

Comment: Worth to mention the five minutes grace period, during which edits won't create a new revision.

Comment: what if I put sensetive data and want to remove it?