# User requests their own question be removed due to sensitive information

Tags: support, moderation, privacy

I have a question that has been flagged by the asker for removal because they say it contains private information that shouldn't be in the public domain. However they don't specify what elements they want removed. Also I don't see anything obviously confidential in there.

The question has votes and has answers with votes too, so I don't really want to remove it altogether.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: LOL, does it look like homework?

Comment: @MartinJames Nah. But there are names in there that may be brand-names or something like that. Or could just be Lorem Ipsum placeholder text. Hard to tell really.

Comment: I don't see why you should remove anything, (unless a court order forces you to).

Comment: @MartinJames If a question has no votes or answers then I'd be happy to remove it as nobody is losing out that way. But yes, if they posted something in this cc-by-sa site then it's not really their content anymore so deleting it would have consequences to those who have put effort into answering it.

Comment: If it's sensible information, there is a way of removing it, without make it even appear in the revisions. Moderators can redact revisions.

Comment: [The internet... is written in ink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HbrQMgOUFw)

Answer (score 9):

Decline the flag, tell them to edit out the private bits without ruining the question or invalidating the answers.

If they ruin the question or invalidate the answers, roll it back.

If you end up having to suspend them because they're trying to vandalize their own post and refuse to communicate, probably worth telling them to contact us. (We deal with this sort of thing a lot - everything from folks posting code that wasn't theirs, to folks who cheated on their homework and are trying not to get caught)

Comment: When a flag is declined, they're not told of this in their Inbox, are they? As far as I recall they have to go and view their own profile to see what has happened to their own flags.

Comment: @JonW You can send a mod message.

Comment: Yup. How much work you want to put into this is up to you, @Jon; you can leave 'em a comment, send 'em a message, or just decline the flag - since they didn't give YOU any useful information, I might err on the side of doing less.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the sensitive information is fundamental to the post (i.e. the post makes no sense without it), then there is absolutely no reason to remove the post—simply remove the sensitive information and redact the revisions with the sensitive information.

If it isn't clear what information is sensitive, then OP needs to clarify that. Explain that they need to edit out the information and that you (i.e. a moderator) can redact the information so that it isn't accessible from the revision log. If the request is just an excuse to get their post deleted then tough cookies—lock the post if needs be.

[What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117/307988)

Comment: Yeah, it's the whole explaining back to them part that is the tricky thing. Declining flags doesn't give them instant feedback about it, and sending a mod message seems far too serious for this situation. I also don't really want to guess at what is sensitive (especially if it's in screenshots as that's a lot of effort to go through on my part).

Comment: Worth keeping in mind that if you decline the flag and they go to flag again, the system will give 'em a link to their flag history (and your message) @Jon - so it ain't totally hidden. That's about as much effort as I'd go for, personally.

Comment: True, and most users probably aren't checking their flag history. If they don't give you enough information there isn't much you can do other than mod message though (comment brings it in to the public so probably not the best idea).