# I deleted my question from Stack Overflow. How can I delete the revision history?

Tags: support, revisions-list, security

I deleted my question from Stack Overflow having some sensitive information, but I believe the question is not completely removed from Stack Overflow. It also has a revision history, so I want to remove all the data related to it - snapshot everything. Could anyone properly help me to resolve this matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

Comment: I delete the question but still revision history is there i do the things but not helped me

Comment: It's too late to do anything anyway.  It was too late as soon as you posted the question:(

Comment: Please don't leave out punctuation in anything you write on Stack Exchange sites. This is extremely rude towards your readers.

Comment: i will take care next time @This_is_NOT_a_forum

Answer (score 7):

Mods can redact a revision - you should do a revision with no sensitive information, then do a custom flag asking for a redaction of all of the offending revisions.

Mods will see its redacted, but not the offending information.

Naturally, do this sparingly, and *do* sanitize your code *before* posting it to the public internet in future.

Comment: Yeah thanks I do it lets see what they will do I indeed will take care next time

Comment: how can I delete the screenshot from imgur which is used by stackoverflow?

Comment: ugh. That probably needs a CM - and might take longer. If you haven't already flagged the post - might want to include that you need that in your flag

Comment: But I already flagged the question I already contact the support for this

Comment: So you should wait for their response.  It won’t be immediate

Comment: its done everything I flag 2 times but issue is completely resolved by legal@stackoverflow.com I sent an email to legal@stackoverflow.com they send me an email and I went to https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/ then after a  day everything is done......  Please take care posting anything that shouldn't be in public but if you did something wrong so just suddenly email to  legal@stackoverflow.com indeed they will help you.