# Confidentiality contract when writing code. Developer questions in SO

Tags: discussion, licensing

I don't know if this is the right place for this questions, but I find that is a proper place because is related with SO.

I work in a company that has a **confidentiality contract** with the code generated. This is: is not possible to publish the code.

Now, many of the developers of the company use **Stack Overflow** for support. This implies that little parts of the code would be published.

The clients want us to eliminate the questions with their code. Is not possible to edit the questions to "dissimulate" the code, because the users could see a log of the previous code.

We believe that the chucks of code are not relevant in terms of the whole application.

I'm against deleting the questions because it would damage the reputation of others or creating voids with some relevant questions that could -or not- be useful to other users.

Do you have similar policies in your companies? How do you manage it? What are your suggestions.

**Stack Overflow is by FAR better in term of knowledge and experience than any other of my collegues**

Comment: As an aside: the [Stack Overflow crew can delete old revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision). But of course, all of us would like them to spend their valuable time on other things... Also, as you seem to care about reputation of others (good!), which implies upvoted answers, [you cannot delete your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471).

Comment: thank you! Already edited!

Comment: We've had some incidents recently which would probably cause most companies loose their $||!& if they saw what users have copypasted right into their questions.

Comment: @Arjan: should I contact developers to delete older entries?

Comment: I don't know, Kani; see Contact Us in the footer. However, they tend to monitor this site quite well, so maybe they saw this question and decided not to bother. Note that by using this site, you're adhering to the [CC BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), so you cannot force the content to be deleted, and it might be in the public data dumps already, or scraped. It might also matter if the posts still make sense without the code, and if the team feels it is really that secret. Anyhow: before asking for *older* revisions to be deleted, you need to edit the questions.

Comment: understood. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally part of your debugging process should be to isolate small areas of non-functional code and produce generic test cases to establish what is going wrong.  In these instances, posting your test code should be fine as it is intended to demonstrate a problem, and is not going into the application verbatim.

In the past I have tried to avoid posting anything specific that could cause the code to be identified as part of the application, even if that just means renaming variables and functions, and removing comments (or rewriting them to make more sense as an accompaniment to the snippet).

Comment: Agreed, a small code snippet without context isn't giving anything confidential away.

Comment: I believe the same. Being ultra-strict in the polices of confidentiality is no-sense. Nevertheless, I can not say **NO** to me overlords :/