# "Full Site" Profile page layout from mobile device

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, profile-page, full-site

The layout of the SO profile page looks very squished:

**SO**:

[image]
[image]

**MSO** (looks fine):

[image]
[image]

Comment: There's a reason we have a mobile site ya know...

Comment: And theres a reason you have a "Full Site" link too... ;).  I  personally prefer scrolling & zooming on the full site b/c the mobile site just lacks a lot of key elements that I've gotten used to.

Comment: it looks fine on my iPhone 4S, latest iOS...not sure how you're getting that behavior unless you're missing a stylesheet

Comment: Looks fine on my iPhone 4, iOS 4, too. The mobile site is great, but like you, I prefer the full site.

Comment: Looks fine on Android ICS too. Only [the footer is a bit odd](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9OJ6H.png), both on SO and MSO.

Comment: (You know these screenshots include personal details?)

Comment: Maybe it's my phone then if noone can repro.  @Arjan Oh, I guess it does have my name/age/email... I'll edit that out when I get to a computer.

Comment: Age is always displayed, but date of birth, email address and real name are not. Of course, editing does not delete the revision history... (See [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but as of a few days ago the profile page on SO looks normal again.