# Remove part of a question for privacy reasons?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, privacy

Is there a way to remove part of a question so that those parts are not visible in the revisions? I need the three commented lines, beginning with `Doesn't work` removed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940064/save-word-document-thats-been-created-dynamically-using-savefiledialog) and any other sections that contain a directory path name. I foolishly didn't check my code before I copied it, and for privacy reasons, I need these parts removed. I deleted these parts of the question in an edit, but I don't want them visible through revisions, either. Thank you.

Comment: You can just edit those parts out, or do you want them out of the revision history as well?

Comment: Yes, I want them out of the revision history as well, if possible. I revised my question a few minutes ago to include that I edited them out of the question.

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't see anything there anyone could use in a meaningful way. If I'm close enough to get to your HD, it's too late anyway.

Comment: I realise that might be the case, but I would still like the information removed. Is this possible?

Comment: `goat.bmp` must be something really embarrassing. :^p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It is possible to delete revisions entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision/86202#86202), but only developers can do that.

What you'll need to do is edit the offending parts out of your post, then flag it for moderator attention explaining that you want a revision deleted. You might want to mention the revision number as well just so there's no confusion.

Moderators can't actually act on that flag, but as far as I know, flags calling for dev-only tasks like [anonymizing a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki/96746#96746) or revision deletion are forwarded to developers.

Comment: I flagged the question and mentioned both this question and the revision number in my flag. How long does that normally take? Not more than a few weeks, I hope.

Comment: @pythonscript I removed your original revision. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - If I visit this link (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10940064/revisions) I still see the data in revision 3 (the commented out section and the file paths)

Comment: @AnnaLear - My apologies. I hadn't updated my browser's cache, so your changes were not showing up. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

A *directory path name*?

Please, when they are this trivial, do us a favor and suffer the consequences of your error with quiet dignity.

Its kind of a pain in the butt for mods to arrange fixes for these situations.  In cases where *actual, important* secret info is released,

1. Delete the post in question (if you can)
2. Edit out the secret info *without defacing the content of the question/answer*
3. Flag and ask for the edit history to be purged