# is the answer I deleted still visible?

Tags: support

I deleted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9763749/93394) back in March, but it is still visible (although greyed out and labeled with the tag `deleted by owner Mar 20 at 20:07`). Can others see this too, or is it only visible to me because I was the author? (I also have a second post on that page that was selected by the OP as the answer; I'm not talking about that one.)

Comment: *I can see your answer!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's visible to you, developers, moderators and anyone with 10k+ reputation. From the ["Moderator Tools" privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools):

> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except
>   developers, moderators, and other fellow users with this privilege.

I, for example, can see the deleted answer you link to in your question, since I have over 10k repuation on SO.

As noted in the comments, however, 10k+ users *cannot* see the deleted post unless they visit the question page directly. For example, this is what I see when I look at your recent answers:

[image]

As you can see, only your other answer on that question shows up.

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to completely delete it? Do moderators have the privilege to delete answers completely?

Comment: @kmote: As far as I know, not even moderators can do that. Delevopers can, but they do so rarely. If there's something you **must** have deleted (e.g., if accidentally posted sensitive information), you can [send an email](http://stackoverflow.com/help/other) to request deletion.

Comment: No, it is a very rare circumstance for content to be deleted completely. But note that 10K+ users can only see the content with a direct link, it does not show up in your answer history on your profile. Developers and moderators, however, have greater access to such history.

Comment: No, @kmote, moderators don't, but developers can, also partly: [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)

Comment: Seeing deleted answers is important for those who have the right to vote to undelete answers...

Comment: @dennis well, if you let a mod know they can usually get a comm team member on  it asap. Whereas team@SO.com is pretty slow, iirc

Comment: @anthony actually, with the size of SO, it's pretty common. 1-2 a day I think.