# Removing someone's private information and edit history to protect them

Tags: feature-request, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

I could not find a relevant Meta question for this issue.

I've come across a couple of questions where someone copy and pastes their code, url, etc and it contains personal information they most certainly did not intend to share. This could be a google key, token, or password.

As editors we can go through and remove this for them but because of the nature of the site it maintains a history. Is there any talk of a way to vote that a piece of history be permanently removed? Or at least have the ability for Moderators to remove the history.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information

Comment: Related: [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)

Comment: See also [Passwords in Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43103/), [What to do if user inadvertently includes email in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61031/), [What is proper etiquette when someone posts copyrighted material?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48364/) and [I need to remove a question with sensitive data?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62094/).

Comment: @All I promise I did spend some time searching. I figured this MUST of come up before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would have to be a developer removing the information from the database. Edits from moderators are the same as from anyone else - they get recorded in the edit history.

The best thing to do is make the edit so the information isn't immediately visible and then flag the question/answer or e-mail the team (see the foot of every page).

Comment: True, but to add to that: team members [do have a nice button for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision). It's not some manual database update.

Comment: That seems reasonable as these are edge cases that typically don't happen. I appreciate the quick feedback.

Answer (score 13):

We've had a few rare occurrences of this sort of thing in the past.  Diamond moderators can't remove it from the revision history, but Community Managers and developers can.  You can still flag it for moderator attention and we'll escalate it to the Community/dev teams.  You can also contact team@stackoverflow.com to get the revision history changed.