# A question includes sensitive material, such as software license keys, that even when edited out still show up in the history

Tags: discussion, feature-request, piracy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions with proprietary or confidential information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information)

In a recent question on SuperUser (not including the link, since it will further spread the sensitive info), the user included Windows XP Pro license keys in their question.

While these were immediately edited out, anyone that knows how to use the site will simply go to the edit history and grab them.

Since questions like these may be valid but contain sensitive info, what is the course of action? Delete it? Or is there a moderator/high rep tool that can modify edit history?

If not, a tool like this may be needed for high rep users/moderators to permanently remove sensitive information like this.

Answer (score 5):

You could just flag it to moderators to erase/merge those revisions.